# In Rcpp, how can I use a variable declared as Nullable?

Tags: r, null, rcpp

I'm new to Rcpp but proficient in R. I'm trying to write an Rcpp function for which an argument can be entered as `NULL`. In Rcpp, my understanding is that that means declaring the variable as "Nullable" in the function arguments, testing whether the input object is NULL using `.isNotNULL()`, and assigning a new variable the value of the original argument (following the directions described [here](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/optional-null-function-arguments/)).

When I attempt run the following code, I get an error that says `use of undeclared identifier 'x'`:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector test(Nullable<NumericVector> x_) {
  if (x_.isNotNull()) {
    NumericVector x(x_);
  }
//Other stuff happens
  if (x_.isNotNull()) {
    return x;
  } else {
    NumericVector y = NumericVector::create(3);
    return y;
  }
}
```

The actual function I'm writing uses `x` downstream in a loop if `x_` is found not to be `NULL`. All the examples of nullable arguments I've seen use the newly assigned variable only within the `if` statement and not outside it. How can I use `x` in subsequent code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should study local and global variables in C++.

This works:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector test(Nullable<NumericVector> x_) {
  NumericVector x;
  if (x_.isNotNull()) {
    x = x_;
  }
  //Other stuff happens
  if (x_.isNotNull()) {
    return x;
  } else {
    NumericVector y = NumericVector::create(3);
    return y;
  }
}
```

However, I would restructure the code instead and avoid duplicating the `if` conditions:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector test(Nullable<NumericVector> x_) {
  NumericVector x;
  if (x_.isNull()) {
    x = NumericVector::create(3);
    return x;
  }
  
  x = x_;
  //Other stuff happens
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this advice! I'm surprised `if` statements engage the local/global distinction. To me all the variables look local since they all exist within `test`. Unfortunately I cannot retain my code within the first `if` because `x` acts kind of as a tuning parameter in a more complicated loop that occurs later. This was just a minimal reproducible example. I'll try this out in my code and see if it helps.